# How do I bake a high poly sculpt onto a low poly mesh?

Tags: texture-baking, sculpting, baking, displacement

I've gone through as many questions as I can but I still don't understand how to bake a high poly sculpt onto a low poly mesh.
I have these two objects, one is high poly and sculpted and one is low poly and not sculpted. I wish to transfer the sculpted texture to the low poly. How might I go about baking??

After Baking:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that you have in mind baking normals from high to low poly mesh: http://bfy.tw/Frf6

Comment: That's exactly what I mean thank you. I didn't know what they were called.

Comment: @LukeD I followed everything it told me to do but my low poly stayed the exact same and nothing changed. Please explain why this happened (I added the images from after I baked it).

Comment: For the beginning, set Bias to 0 while Distance to something more than 0.1. Then start changing values while looking at how bake changes. In most cases you can leave Bias at 0 and have bake captured. Needless to say, objects have to be in the same place in 3d space.

Comment: @MrZak thanks, I'm not sure how to make them in the exact same place as the centre of my low poly object isn't centred.

Comment: Center of mass of the objects should be roughly in the same place as they are nearly the same in their volume. In case of first screenshot above, select lowpoly, Shift+S > Cursor To Selected to snap it to the highpoly, then enter Edit mode for lowpoly and use Selection To Cursor (Offset). When in Object mode, objects should be aligned. Normally lowpoly shouldn't change its position as I assume you modelled it atop of highpoly with snapping during transform or Shrinkwrap

Comment: @MrZak Do you know what the different colours on the normal map mean? For example I have parts that look good and are purple/blue and then other parts that are green/yellow

Comment: Appearing of other colors means normal map tries to contain too much of displacement from highpoly and fails. Think of it in terms of colors, where RGB is XYZ adjacently, which means green is shift towards Y. See also http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Normal_map, e.g. this thread http://polycount.com/discussion/146667/a-practical-guide-on-normal-mapping-for-games